How do I write cypress test to catch the ant successful message pop up?
Currently, right after clicking the "Join" button, it shows the successfully pop up message right away and my cy.get("div.ant-message-custom-content.ant-message-success").should("be.visible"); line is not able to catch it. Here is my full test:
    context("Student join a class", () => {
      context("Using account having joined no classes", () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          cy.visit("http://localhost:3000/auth/login");
    
          cy.fixture("student/student-no-classes.json").then((data) => {
            cy.login(data.username, data.password);
          });
    
          cy.url().should("include", "/home");
        });
        it("Join class using valid invite code from home page", function () {
          cy.fixture("student/successful-join-with-code-response1.json").then((response) => {
            this.joinResponse = response;
          });
    
          cy.intercept("POST", "/v1/classes/join-with-code/", (req) => {
            req.reply({
              statusCode: 200,
              body: this.joinResponse,
            });
          }).as("join-class");
    
          cy.get("button").contains("Get Started").click();
          cy.get("div").contains("Join a class").click();
          cy.fixture("student/invite-code-valid").then((data) => {
            cy.get("input#code").type(data.inviteCode);
          });
          cy.get("button").contains("Join").click();
    
          cy.get("div.ant-message-custom-content.ant-message-success").should("be.visible");
          cy.fixture("student/invite-code-valid").then((data) => {
            cy.url().should.be(`http://localhost:3000/classes/feeds/${data.slug}`);
          });
        });
      });
    });



The div.ant-message-success selector works for me.

Changing that line to cy.contains("div", "Joined class successfully").should("be.visible"); solved my problem. Using selector class might have caused it to not locate the pop up.
